# Как подключить базу данных sql расположенную на компьютере подключенном через swith

Tags: c#, sql-server

Пишу приложение на с#, работающее в сети нескольких компьютеров, соединенных через switch, в общем просто пингуются.

Пытаюсь подключить бд SQL Express на компе выступающим местом хранения бд, все работает, но с другого, т. е. удаленно нет. настроил все и тсп, и веб браузер, и брандмаузер.

Ошибка типа login failed with this type of windows identification.
SQL Express ставился с VS 2008.

Comment: Свитч тут не причем если он не "тупой" и на нем не настроен сегментация трафика, машина с бд пингуется? Судя по ошибки очевидно, что аутентификация.

Answer (score 1):

[Enabling Network Access to SQL Server Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165647(v=sql.90).aspx)

скорее всего эта сслыка подойдет:

[How to: Enable Network Access in SQL Server Configuration Manager (SQL Server Express)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Express можно ставить только локально, удаленно к нему не подключишься. Можно создать службу, которая и будет осуществлять доступ к БД.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке - у вас две машины, обе не в домене. В таком случае SQL Server не будет пускать пользователей с другой машины под Windows Authentication.

Нужно включить [Mixed Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188670.aspx) в свойствах сервера, включить пользователя sa (или создать нового), задать ему пароль, и использовать имя/пароль вместо Windows Authentication при подключении.

Строка подключения при этом будет выглядеть так:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
```

Password=myPassword;